# How to create an icon for google play console upload

Tags: android, google-play, icons

I try to upload an icon for a new android application on the google play console.

Icon

[image: the app icon]
<sub>(source: [imagineclan.de](https://imagineclan.de/files/shoppinglist_icon.png))</sub>

Screenshot

[image: the app icon]
<sub>(source: [imagineclan.de](https://imagineclan.de/files/shoppinglist_screen_01.PNG))</sub>

I tried to upload the icon (also a screen) I made with GIMP, but it won't work. Without any message. Does anyone of you guys know, what's wrong with the images or how i can create a proper one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all, who also can't upload an app icon for the store. First you need to upload an apk, then it will work. It is kind of confusing because the tab 'Store-Entry' pops up first.